# jquery getElementsByClassName find partial class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use the javascript function getElementsByClassName to loop in some html divs that don't have the exactly class name, but it starts with the same text: "akordeon-item"

So, the html text looks like this:

```
<div class="akordeon-item akordeon-item-first">

<div>
    <span class="userid">
          blabla@yahoo.com
    </span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="akordeon-item akordeon-item-second">

<div>
    <span class="userid">
          john_doe@yahoo.com
    </span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="akordeon-item akordeon-item-third">

<div>
    <span class="userid">
          john_doe2@yahoo.com
    </span>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="akordeon-item akordeon-item-fourth">

<div>
    <span class="userid">
          john_doe3@yahoo.com
    </span>
</div>
```

Also, the javascript code I tried is this one:

```
var slides = getElementsByClassName(".akordeon-item");
for(var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++)
{
   alert("element : "+slides[i]);
}
```

I also tried searching for this string inside the getElementsByClassName method : "akordeon-item"

How can I make this loop work?
Please help...

Comment: Question seems unclear..!

Comment: Remove the period `.`, `getElementsByClassName` takes the literal class name, not a selector

Comment: since u marked jquery: $('[class^="text"]')

Comment: Note that unless the search expression has an anchor, doing this will inspect *all* elements in your document.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is [a bunch of special selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) you can make use of:

```
^= is starts with

$= is ends with    
=  is exactly equal
!= is not equal
*= is contains
```

Try:

```
$.each($('[class^="akordeon-item"]'), function(key, value) {
    console.log(key, value);
});
```

- **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BK8sb/)**
- [`$.each` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Alternative ways to iterate over the set:

```
$('[class^="akordeon-item"]').each(function(key, value) {
    console.log(key, value);
});
```

Or using a `for` loop:

```
var slides = $('[class^="akordeon-item"]');
for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    console.log(slides[i]);
}
```

Comment: And this would be `function(index, value) {` more relevant.. since it wont get any key values..

Comment: @SomnathKharat the first word in the title is `jquery`. Also, the question is tagged under `jquery`.

Comment: he added jquery to his tags

Comment: and what it would harm if do this jQuery way @somnathkharat.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the answers, this one suits me best. Thanks a lot @martynas!

Comment: I know the answer is 1,5 years old, but what is the reason you use `$.each($(selector)` instead of `$(selector).each()`?

Comment: @Rvervuurt No reason - you can do it any way you like :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div[class^="akordeon-item"]').each(function(index){});
```